# One Class Pattern for All Web API calls

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

In my app I have a-lot of Web API calls which returns me JSON. I am trying to do this thing simple. I don't want to create `AsyncTask` in every fragment. I have tried many things but nothing give me the solution how to do this. I need one Class solution in which I call a method with a url argument and get result in calling fragment or activity. Can someone share best practice to do this?

I have tried otto library but It seems it don't fulfill my requirements.

Comment: At-Last I found it. Volley Library is the final destiny. :) feeling Happy. ;)
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/

Answer (score 0):

Web communication should not be done in main thread, therefore, some kind of threading is necessary. I think AsyncTask is the easiest way. I suggest creating abstract class, implementing network-stuff, and leave parsing output for child classes. Something like this:

```
abstract class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<...>{
    DownloadJSON(List<NameValuePair> httpParams){...}
    JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls){... return mJSONObject}
    abstract void onPostExecute(JSONObject json);

}
```

You may override `doInBackground` for further background parsing or just display contents in `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the library called [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). It turns your REST API into a Java interface and has asynchronous execution of requests. It even converts your JSON response into Java objects.